# PHP method input parameters

Tags: php, json, web-services, soap

I don't know PHP, just the basics (if so...).

I have a method in my web service like this:

```
$server->register(
    'registerDeviceOnServer', //method name
    array('uniqueIdentifier' => 'xsd:string','deviceName' => 'xsd:string', 'systemVersion' => 'xsd:string', 'deviceModel' => 'xsd:string', 'userLocation_Locality' => 'xsd:string', 'userLocation_CountryCode' => 'xsd:string' ), //input data
    array('xmlReturn' => 'xsd:string'), //output data
    'urn:server.AAAA', //namespace
    'urn:server.AAAA#registerDeviceOnServer', //soapaction
    'rpc', //style
    'encoded', //use
    'regista o iDevice' //info for documentation
);

function registerDeviceOnServer($uniqueIdentifier,$deviceName,$systemVersion,$deviceModel,$userLocation_Locality,$userLocation_CountryCode)
{
    //some code that talks to the database
    //inserting the data into a table
    //
    //the SQL code works fine. I've tested.
}
```

When I call the web service, the data does not come in that exact order as it is declared in the php method. Does it have to come in that order, or does PHP assign the data to the vars?

SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<registerDeviceOnServer xmlns="urn:server.AAAA">
<uniqueIdentifier>VVVVVVVVVVVVWWWWWWWW</uniqueIdentifier>
<userLocation_CountryCode>n/a</userLocation_CountryCode><deviceModel>iPhone Simulator</deviceModel><systemVersion>4.0</systemVersion><deviceName>iPhone OS</deviceName><userLocation_Locality>n/a</userLocation_Locality>
</registerDeviceOnServer>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So, how can I work this out?

Thanks,

RL

Comment: What *is* the parameter order *inside* the function? Or are you referring to the XML of the SOAP Request only that uses *named* parameters? I would expect that the soap server assigns the values to the exact parameter based on their name.

Comment: What i mean is: in the function, the first parameter is 'uniqueIdentifier'. If, in the soap xml, the first parameter i pass is 'userLocation_CountryCode', the function receives that value and throws into the 'userLocation_CountryCode' or 'uniqueIdentifier'?

Comment: Just run it, it should work fine.

Comment: that's the issue: i run and, inside the method, i have a sql statement and it does interact with the DB. I think it's because of my above question. I just want to get shore that this was not the issue...

Comment: Okay, you can debug what is passed as parameters to your function with `var_dump(func_get_args()); die();`. This will output all function arguments given in their order and then stopping any further execution.

Comment: Hi, the problem subsist. When I send the JSON request, it does not add the sent text to the correspondent key. Why?

Comment: What you're doing should work. I'd like to see the code where you're sending the request to the server. I'm assuming that's php too? Also I'm not too sure about using NuSOAP the php library that comes with php works great!

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I can now see that you are actually using `nusoap.php` and not PHP's own `SoapServer`.

Check [this forum post](http://old.nabble.com/NuSoap-transition----Question-on-parameter-ordering.-td30156593.html):

> I had a similar issue recently which was caused because I didn't
>   provide a WSDL url to my SoapServer constructor.
>
> Apparently the soap server can only map message arguments / parameters
>   when it has a valid WSDL for reference (which more or less made sense 
>   to me afterwards).

Does this help you?

Comment: in my post i have the function in php, and mu soap request. What other information do you need do see what's wrong?

Comment: what is $server? how is it defined? How is registerDeviceOnServer being called?

Comment: Hi, registerDeviceOnServer is being called in the soap request.
The $server:
$server = new soap_server
$server->configureWSDL('myapp','urn:myapp');

Comment: the method to register:

 function register($name,$in=array(),$out=array(),$namespace=false,$soapaction=false,$style=false,$use=false,$documentation='',$encodingStyle=''){
  global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS;

Comment: if i call from the URL the file.php, it shows all my methods. Is that it?
I have very low experience with php. Can you help me do it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP, check the link in my last comment

Answer (score 0):

As @akirk says, maybe your problem is related to the WSDL. Make sure that the parameters are in the **same order** that's in the WSDL

Comment: I have wsdl methods. The question is that in the JSON request, the parameters are not in the same order has they are in the WSDL. Do they really have to be in the same order?

Comment: Yes, i understand you problem. Take a look to this post, that supports what im saying. http://snook.ca/archives/other/soap_request_pa

Comment: So, what you are saying is that what I want is not possible?

Comment: No, what you want to do **is** possible! Check your WSDL, the one you are using in `$server->configureWSDL('myapp','urn:myapp');` And then make sure that your register function `register($name,$in=array(),$out=array(),$namespace=false,$soapaction=false,$styl‌​e=false,$use=false,$documentation='',$encodingStyle='')` has the params in the same order.

Comment: I found the function:

function configureWSDL($serviceName,$namespace = false,$endpoint = false,$style='rpc', $transport = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http', $schemaTargetNamespace = false)
{
} Can we talk by mail and i post the answer here? I'm kind of confused...

Comment: Rui, you paste here (on your question) two things. First, how you "register" your method. you are using nuSOAP (as someone said before). So you register that function. Second you paste the SOAP request. How are you "doing" the call to the web service? please, look at this page [Programming with NuSOAP Using WSDL](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprogwsdl.htm) this page will help you a lot. Take a look at it, and then ask here again. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, I'm doing the soap request thru XML, using <name>RUI<\name> <country>PORTUGAL<\country> for example. And on the method in php, I have the country first, and then the Name. And what happens, is that the name is set on country, so hi's not respecting the var names, hi's respecting the order in wish the request is made...